# Symfony2 dynamic select box - validation fails

Tags: symfony

I'm making an application where users can add their pets (cats and dogs). 
The app has an "pet input form", where cat/dog breeds are translated into multiple languages, depending on the user. The breeds are added dynamically (using AJAX), based on the pet type selection - so if user selects "dog", the "breed" selection box is populated with dog breeds, and vice versa.
The problem is, that after submit I get an error:

> Unable to reverse value for property path "breed": The choice "[Translated breed value]" does not exist or is not unique

Is there either a way to disable validation for the select box, or either make it so that it "accepts" translated values as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always set field to mapped false, but then you must handle binding it to entity yourself

but of course this is probably not needed in this case, while loading via ajax just set select options like that

```
<select>
<option value='notTranslatedName'>translatedName</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I managed to solve this, the problem was that I was using the translated name for both times.